# Running mod_perl on El capitan

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, perl, open-source

I'm trying to run mod_perl on El capitan.

### Process

1. Following http://blog.n42designs.com/blog/2014/10/23/compiling-mod-perl-for-apache-2-dot-4-on-os-x-10-dot-10-yosemite/ an https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240610/how-to-install-mod-perl-2-0-10-in-apache-2-4-on-os-x-el-capitan
2. The correct repository is different for El capitan, so use `svn co  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/perl/modperl/tags/2_0_9/`

   2.`perl Makefile.PL MP_CCOPTS=-std=gnu89 ; make ; sudo make install` I could get `/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so`
3. In `/etc/apache2/other` directory, I added `cgi.conf` with the following content.

---

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
#PerlModule ModPerl::Registry

<Location "/Library/WebServer/Documents/cgi/">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

I copied simple perl cgi script in the `/Library/WebServer/Documents/cgi/` directory, but instead of execution the perl script, the perl code is shown.

What might be wrong?

### ADDED

After adding these lines in the conf file:

```
<Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
    Options +ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
</Files>
```

I have errors instead:

```
[perl:error] [pid 26307] [client ::1:60248] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::PerlRun': Can't locate ModPerl/PerlRun.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ModPerl::PerlRun module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mac OS X, `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables` has already setup, so there should be no configuration. So, just copying `echo.pl` in the directory, and use the perl script with `localhost/cgi-bin/echo.pl`.

### To make it work anyway

We need a `ModPerl::PerlRun` to install the CPAN module before the compilation.

```
sudo cpan ModPerl::PerlRun
```

This also creates and installs the `perl_mod.so`, but this breaks the apache, so we need to rebuild the module. This is the working configuration.

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so

<Location "/Library/WebServer/Documents/cgi/">
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
    Options +ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
</Files>
```

Now `localhost/cgi/echo.pl` is the address to access.